# Getting values of checked checkboxes in a form to separate strings (dynamic naming)

Tags: javascript, dynamic

The title explains most of it..

```
var formobj = document.h1;
for (var j = 0; j < formobj.elements.length; j++) {
            if (formobj.elements[j].type == "checkbox" && formobj.elements[j].checked) {
                    //WHAT GOES HERE?
            }
```

I would like to dynamically name strings something like string1, string2, string3, etc after the values of any checked checkboxes. How can I dynamically name them?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically name?" Set the value of the string, or the variable name, or something else? What do you want to do with this "dynamic name?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if I understand the question correctly, but wouldn't it just be:

```
formobj.elements[j].id = 'string'+j;
```

Comment: I think that'd work, but that would name them depending on what number element it is. How can I just name them 1, 2, 3 etc?

Comment: You just replace j with a integer or string (`formobj.elements[j].id = 'string1';` OR `formobj.elements[j].id = 'string'+varName;`). I used j because that way the number would increase everytime the next element came around :)